# loadrunner on Linux and system monitoring scenario

Tags: loadrunner

How i can install load runner on Linux/Ubuntu environment ?
I need a clear steps I have already tried to install it on ubuntu Desktop system but failed to make it

and how i can make a scenario for monitoring system resources ?
I need a whole idea about making scripts for that

thanks

Comment: Can you paste the error you are getting when doing make?

Comment: it's not a matter of error .. i have installed load-runner on windows system and then i make a vmware virtual machine including ubuntu desktop .. and i have another one includes Linux red hat .. the point i don't know from where i need to start .. what i should do or make ? i am totally lost

Comment: Are you trying the steps in the installation guide, chapter 3 (Chapter 3: Installing the Load Generator on Linux)?

Comment: @moha sorry cant help you on that. But i can only say you have to start by Install a Load Generator on Linux with the Setup Wizard and follow the steps in the Guide.

Comment: can you direct me how you install it .. i mean tell me the steps .. and can you  give me a link to guide please

Comment: It is in your LR installation package called "HPE LoadRunner Installation Guide.pdf"

Comment: yes @Buzzy i am trying to do those steps but i couldn't

Comment: i stopped at step 4 .. i didn't know what to do on changing directory ? so i couldn't continue

Comment: Could you please open a support case and one of our support staff will help you with the steps. Thanks.

Comment: i tried but they don't support owners of free editions

Answer (score 0):

Dont use scripts for monitoring system resources.  This is why, since the very first version of LoadRunner, there have been ways to monitor directly system stats on various operating systems. These operating systems include LINUX where you have at least three methods to collect monitoring stats directly and one indirect method.

Direct:

- RSTATD
- SNMP
- SiteScope integration which is running a command shell and pulling system metrics into monitors

Indirect:

- Run a RTE user, you issue the commands through the command shell and convert them to datapoints.  This is essentially what SiteScope is doing and you would be spending hours and dollars reproducing this effort
- run a shell script and output the data to a file
- Schedule a perfmon dump to a file

for the last two possibiities you will find ample information in the analysis guide on how to reintegrate data from a decoupled monitor set which contains the values in a file.  File formats are also discussed.

Apparently someone has asked you to perform in this role without the benefit of product training or a mentor.  It would be worthwhile to read the controller documentation on monitors, the virtual user generator guide on RTE and the analysis guide on importation of external monitor data.